# Linq to Entities - Filter on any item in one list belonging to another list

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

Here is my scenario. I have a Document class. The document is associated with a DocumentClasses table through a many to many relationship, so a document can have one or more classes. When running a search, the user can choose to filter documents by class. So, I need to be able to append a where clause to my query if the user chooses to select any classes. The logic is that if the document is assigned to any of the classes in the classes the user selected, the document should be returned. So the basic query needed in pseudo code. So basically, if any number in list A belongs to list B, then return the record.

I have tried this (RestrictByClasses is just a List(Of Integer)):

```
query = query.where(Function(resultItem) RestrictByClasses.Contains(resultItem.DocumentClassIds.Any())
```

But I get the following exception:

```
The nested query is not supported. Operation1='Case' Operation2='Collect'
```

Is there any way to get linq to filter records out like this?

Thanks!

UPDATE:

After doing a little more debugging, I think that it is more to do with how I am projecting onto the object in order to load it with values that can be used to filter. Here is how I am doing the projection:

```
Dim query = From document In dbContext.Documents
                        Select New FeeAndReceptionReportIntermediateItem With
                                 {
                                     .BookTypeId = If(restrictByBookTypes AndAlso document.DocumentInstruments.Any(), document.DocumentInstruments.FirstOrDefault().Instrument.BookTypeId, Nothing),
                                     .CustomerId = document.CustomerId,
                                     .DocumentClassIds = If(restrictByDocumentClasses, document.DocumentClasses.Select(Function(group) group.ClassId), Nothing),
                                     .DocumentId = document.DocumentId,
                                     .DocumentNumber = document.DocumentNumber,
                                     .DepartmentId = document.DepartmentId,
                                     .InstrumentGroupIds = If(restrictByInstrumentGroup, document.DocumentInstruments.FirstOrDefault().Instrument.InstrumentGroups.Select(Function(group) group.InstrumentGroupId), Nothing),
                                     .RecordDateTime = document.RecordDateTime,
                                     .RestrictedInstrument = (includeRestrictedDocuments AndAlso document.DocumentInstruments.Any() AndAlso document.DocumentInstruments.FirstOrDefault().Instrument.Restricted)
                                 }
```

I think it is complaining about how the .DocumentClassIds and .InstrumentGroupId's are being loaded into the POCO object (FeeAndReceptionReportIntermediateItem). I would really like to load these up in the initial query, before a .ToList() has been called and I would really like to not even do the join if the user did not pass in the restrictions that require me to create the join, that's why I am using the navigation properties and an if statement when loading these collecctions, because I am assuming if "restrictByDocumentClasses" is false, the navigation property won't be accessed and the join won't be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works as a general pattern.  The first line gets an IQueryable<> from the DbSet<>.  The select does this for us, so that we can continue reusing query to hold our query as we build it up.  Then just keep adding on If...Then...query=query.Where(...)...Endif to continue whittling down the resultset.

```
var query=db.MyTable.Select(x=>x);

if (RestrictByClasses.Any())
  query=query.Where(r => 
    r.DocumentClasses.Select(x=>x.ClassId)
    .Intersect(RestrictByClasses)
    .Any());

 if (RestrictBySomethingElse)
   query=query.Where(x=>SomethingElse)
```

I think this is the equivalent in VB.NET:

```
Dim query = db.MyTable.[Select](Function(x) x)

If RestrictByClasses.Any() Then
    query = query.Where(Function(r) r.DocumentClasses.Select(Function(group) group.ClassId).Intersect(RestrictByClasses).Any())
End If

'Repeat as necessary
If RestrictBySomethingElse Then
    query = query.Where(Function(x) SomethingElse)
End If
'End repeat

' Rest here is pseudo code
' Sort
SELECT/SWITCH sortonfield
CASE 'name': query=query.OrderBy(Function(x) x.name)
CASE 'dob': query=query.OrderBy(Function(x) x.dob)
DEFAULT: query=query.OrderBy(Function(x) x.id)
END CASE

'Paginate
query=query.Skip((pagenumber-1)*pagesize).Take(pagesize)

'Project
Dim finalresult=query.Select(Function(x) new something {
  name=x.Name,
  id=x.id,
  things=x.things
 });
```

Once all your filters have been put in place (and optionally a sort, and pagination), then project your resultset into whatever you need.

Comment: That might be the right syntax, but I still get the same error. I think I need to project the query out to an object and then add the where condition to a second linq to objects query. I won't know for sure if this works (returns correct data even if I get past the error) until next week but I will come back and update you. Thanks for the answer, I hope it is what I needed.

Comment: Yeah, I still get the same error with this statement. Bummer.

Comment: @DonnieDarko Changed answer to show how you can do selective filtering, bypassing joins if they aren't necessary for filtering.

Comment: I think I got my projection into my POCO object worked out. I had to actually do the joins in the query rather than using navigation properties. I don't really like this because I didn't want to do the joins if I didn't have to but..

Comment: I am really only after this line: query = query.Where(Function(r) r.DocumentClasses.Select(Function(group) group.ClassId).Intersect(RestrictByClasses).Any()). I think that might work and I do like the use of Intersect, I thought about looking into that to see if I could use it in some way. I think my main errors were just due to how I was projecting and didn't really have anything to do with my .where.

Comment: Will let you know as soon as I can get some unit tests setup if that where is working as I would expect. Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where you are skipping joins. I see where you are conditionally adding to the .where clause, which is exactly what I am doing. But if I need a field that is joined from another table to be used in one of those where clauses, it has to be joined in the original query, no?

Comment: @DonnieDarko No, you don't have to have the children in the original query if you don't want them returned and it is just for possibly using in a where clause.  Not sure why you can't use the navigation properties.  Sounds like your model may be incorrect.

Comment: Because I'm selecting into a POCO object. I can't use the navigation properties in the above code because EF gives me an error, something about not supporting subqueries. I can use them in the "RestrictedGroupInstrument" field, but not in the InstrumentGroupId's or the DocumentClassId's. So, I think I can select the entity back first and then keep dynamically adding the joins as needed until I get to where I need to apply my criteria and select into my POCO object. Sounds good anyway...going to try something like that now. Thanks again for your comments and help with this.

Comment: Sorry, they basically all give me the Does Not support sub queries error as written above (the ones where I am using nav properties), I can get the instrumentGroupIds to go off of a navigation property if I do one join to the instrument and then only go one level into the navigation properties.

Comment: Ok we've gotten a little off topic of my original question, but thanks for sticking in there with me. I've been able to test the .Intersect in the where to accomplish what I originally asked and it looks like it is working well so I will mark you answer as correct. As far as the conditional join, I just ended up doing what I didn't want to do and basically writing three entirely different queries based on the criteria.

Comment: I've tried pretty much every way to get conditional joins where I need them and still be able to load my final object with what I need but there seems to be roadblocks on each of those methods so sometimes it is just better to make different queries. It will work for me for now. Thanks for your help!